# Images not showing on android phone in preview after changing image upload file on phonegap

Tags: android, file-upload, cordova

I am working on phonegap and wrote following code to show preview of image upload file:

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            var img ='<div style="padding:10px; margin:10px;  border: solid 2px #666;float: left; width:30%"><img src="'+ e.target.result+'" width="100%" /></div>';
            $('#images_area').append(img);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}


    $("#image_upload_field").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});
```

This is working on browser but not showing images phonegap on android phone. So I am looking for the reason, why it is happening, it is showing question mark on phone.

Also did this:

```
cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-file.git
cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-file-transfer.git
```

These 2 lines are from userguide of phonegap. And changes in android config and manifest files are also done after executing above 2 lines.

So What is the reason that it isn't working? Please let me know if any idea.

Comment: Could you provide an image-url. Not an example but an image which actually does not work in your app...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            function readURL(input) {
                if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                        var image;
                        var fileName = input.files[0].name;
                        var type = 'image/' + fileName.split('.').pop();
                        if (type == 'image/jpg') {
                            type = 'image/jpeg';
                            image = ((e.target.result).replace('data:base64,/', 'data:' + type + ';base64,/'));
                        } else {
                            image = ((e.target.result).replace('data:base64,', 'data:' + type + ';base64,'));
                        }
                        var img = '<div style="padding:10px; margin:10px;  border: solid 2px #666;float: left; width:30%"><img src="' + image + '" width="100%" /></div>';
                        $('#images_area').append(img);
                    }
                    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
                }
            }

            $("#image_upload_field").change(function () {
                readURL(this);
                });
})
```